# Images won't load from jar file

Tags: java, image, jar

I have tried searching and still haven't got the solution. When I export to a jar file all my images suddenly do not work anymore. They run fine out of eclipse and I have made sure that they are in the jar file. I have tried using get resource methods and making a image-loader class to automatically go up the directory tree but it still fails. Here is what I have done:

```
public static Image load(String path)
{   String temp = path;
    Image image = null;
    try {

     image = new ImageIcon(path).getImage();


    } 

    catch ( Exception e )
    {   
        try {
         while (image == null )
         {
              image = new ImageIcon("../"+ path).getImage();
         }
         if ( path.equals("../../../../../../"+ temp))
         {
             while ( image ==null)
             {
                 image = new ImageIcon("./"+ path).getImage();
             }
         }
        }
        catch ( Exception ae)
        {


        System.err.println("cannot locate image");
    }} 


    return image;
}
```

the path I will send it look as follows: "doc/icon.png"

I have placed all my images in the doc folder, the structure is final Project, inside there is doc folder and then the src folder that contains all the packages.

Comment: print path and see if it is correct

Comment: `if ( path.equals("../../../../../../"+ temp))` what does it mean?

Comment: By the time of deployment, those resources will likely become an [tag:embedded-resource].  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using this:

```
Image.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/filepath/filename").getFile()
```

Comment: Fair enough -> updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "Brute-force" the image path try to figure out what's the path you try to load the image from. You can look it up with the following

```
System.out.println("Path: " + (this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("")).getPath());
```

afterwards try to load it like this or like @Balint Bako allready sed.

```
Image img;
URL url = new File("the path you found out").toURI().toURL();
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
```