# Unable to acces files of other project in a eclipse java project

Tags: java, eclipse

I have two java projects in eclipse Project A and  Project B,  Project A has two folders source and resources, I added Project A in build path of Project B, In Project B I am able to use the classes of Project A but not the files in resources, When I try to open files using FileI/O I get FileNotFoundException.  Can someone help me on this, I am new to eclipse

In project B 
using project A's  file  Sample.txt located at resources folder

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("resources/Sample.txt");

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using please.

Comment: Is the resources folder in the output of that project?

Comment: This issue was answered a few times:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189265/images-wont-load-from-jar-file/17189387#17189387

Comment: Changed my code to use getResourceStream and it worked and added resources folder in build path. Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

Make your resources folder also as a source folder. Select Project A, go to project > properties, under java build path> source tab, add resources folder. This will make sure all your files available in resources are copied to bin folder and can be referred as classpath resource.